# Getting currently focused UIScene when multiple connected scenes are active in foreground

Tags: ipad, xcode11, swift5, uiscene

I have a problem getting the current `UIScene` when multiple scenes are connected.

Specifically, my app (iOS 13) supports multiple windows on the iPad. When I have two windows side by side and I access the apps connected scenes (with `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes`), all of them have the `activationState` set to `.foregroundActive`. But I am actually only interacting with one of them.

I found some code here on stackoverflow to retrieve the current key window (can't remember who it was that posted it) but as you can see it will always return one of the two windows.

```
let keyWindow: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
    .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
    .compactMap({$0})
    .first?.windows
    .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
```

Am I missing some method to determine the last window that was interacted with or are the multiple `.foregroundActive` states a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Although `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` is deprecated after iOS 13.0 by Apple, it seems this attribute can help you find the active one when multiple scenes in the foreground by using:

```swift
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene
```

Comment: Yep & upvoted. This is still true as of iOS 15.0.2 (Nov 2021). All other workarounds do not really work when you put two scenes side by side on the iPad.

Comment: Yep & considering the deprecation: `UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows.firstObject.windowScene`

Comment: It's 2023, and using the deprecated `keyWindow` is still the only reliable function in side-by-side situations on an iPad.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to my problem by refactoring my code so that now I access the current `UIScene`s window through the `window` attribute of any view or view controller. This way I don't need the `keyWindow` anymore.

I think it's probably correct that both windows open next to each other have the `activationState`  `.foregroundActive`

In case anyone needs it, these are the two extensions that helped me get to to current window from anywhere in the app:

```
extension UIViewController {
  var window: UIWindow? {
    return view.window
  }
}

extension UIScene {
  var window: UIWindow? {
    return (delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window
  }
}
```

But the problem still stands if you don't have access to a `UIView`, `UIViewController` or `UIScene`. For example inside a data model with no reference to a view or scene. Then I don't see a way to consistently accessing the correct window the user is interacting with.

Comment: Its very frustrating. In side by side both scene are foreground active. You can actually interact with both scene at the same time using two fingers. Checking if the window is key does not help because is not always the last window that was interacted with.

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension in my project

```
// MARK: - Scene Delegate helpers

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension UIApplication {
    static var firstScene: UIScene? {
        UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
    }

    static var firstSceneDelegate: SceneDelegate? {
        UIApplication.firstScene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate
    }

    static var firstWindowScene: UIWindowScene? {
        UIApplication.firstSceneDelegate?.windowScene
    }
}

// MARK: - Window Scene sugar

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
protocol WindowSceneDependable {
    var windowScene: UIWindowScene? { get }
    var window: UIWindow? { get }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension WindowSceneDependable {
    var windowScene: UIWindowScene? {
        window?.windowScene
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension UIScene: WindowSceneDependable { }

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension SceneDelegate: WindowSceneDependable { }

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension UIViewController: WindowSceneDependable { }

// MARK: - Window sugar

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension UIScene {
    var window: UIWindow? {
        (delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    var window: UIWindow? {
        view.window
    }
}
```

And then I can do this when I have to present something:

```
func present(from navigation: UINavigationController) {
    self.navigation = navigation

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        guard let currentWindowScene = navigation.windowScene else { return }
        myPresenter.present(in: currentWindowScene)
    } else {
        myPresenter.present()
    }
}
```

Using this I can get a window from almost anywhere. But the thing is that it's not possible if I have no access to view-related objects at all. For example, in my auth service I have to use this bullshit:

```
func authorize() {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        guard let currentWindowScene = UIApplication.firstWindowScene else { return }
        presenter.present(in: currentWindowScene)
    } else {
        presenter.present()
    }
}
```

This does not look correct for me, and it works only for the first windowScene.
It's better not to do this just like I did, you have to elaborate on this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solution gives you the last interacted-with `UIScene` without relying on anything but using a `UIWindow` subclass for all your scenes.

```
class Window: UIWindow
{
    static var lastActive: Window?

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
    {
        Self.lastActive = self
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

Now you can access `Window.lastActive` and its associated `windowScene` (`UIWindowScene`/`UIScene`).